# Is it possible to change the HTTP status code returned when proxy_pass gateway is down in nginx?

Tags: http, proxy, nginx

For SEO purposes, we would like to change the HTTP status code returned whenever the backend machine behind nginx goes down for some reason.

We would like to change this to "503 Service Unavailable". As well as provide a Retry-After header to indicated to Google / Bing that the request should be retried in X number of seconds.

Is this possible via nginx?

I am not talking about a custom error page, but rather the status code returned in the header.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think you **will** have to set up a specific error page, however you can achieve what you're looking for if you do. Try this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 502 503 504 =503 @proxyisdown; # always reply with 503
}

location @proxyisdown {
    add_header Retry-After 500 always;
    index my_pretty_error_page.html; 
}
```

If you work it this way you should be able to return the 503 (that's the `=503` part of the `error_page` directive) and retry-after headers with the benefit that your visitors will receive a nicely formatted "oops, we're currently experiencing problems, try again in a few minutes" page rather than a blank "503 you don't really know what this means" page. :)

Comment: will be trying this later on today. i should have been more clear in the question, a custom error page will be used as well... its just that we know how to do that, just did not know how to change the status code / add the retry-after header. anyways, will get back within 12 hours and let you know what we come up with. that being said, this looks exactly like what we are looking for :) thx.

Comment: Updated the answer to give more clarity on returning the required error code.

Comment: Everything works as expected. Except that add_header is not supported by a 503 response in nginx. Check http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,3727 for more info.

Comment: @anonymous-one interesting. seems a little odd that it's not supported. I've added a ticket for this issue.

Comment: i will select this answer regardless as this is the right way to do things. not your fault whoever it may be decided to disallow add_header on >400 status codes. will keep and eye on bleeding edge to see if this is updated. thx!

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/418709/nginx-add-header-for-a-50-page for a full fledged way to do this. It does require a non-standard module, but using this you can add any header you like to 503. Works like a charm!

Comment: Hello from the future! Today you can use `add_header` directive with non-successful response codes by specifying `always` keyword. See the docs: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

Answer (score 3):

Name your error page `/500.html` and:

```
error_page 400 404 500 502 504 =503 /500.html;

# Optional if your public root is set above and the same for error pages,
# I sometimes please them outside the app, which is why I'm including it.
location /500.html {
  root /path/to/public;
}
```

Should work as well and seems a bit simpler to me. Note: it doesn't support the Header either.