# Remapping Nginx 502/504 error from proxy_pass into 408 error

Tags: http, proxy, nginx

I would like to remap the 502 and 504 errors generated by Nginx when it can't talk to the proxy successfully into 408 errors.

To be clear, when Nginx returns 502/504 and no body, it should instead return 408 and still no body.

I tried adding this directive, but it apparently corrupts the response headers:

```
error_page              502 =408;
error_page              504 =408;
```

Any idea how to do remap an Nginx error code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://nginx.org/r/error_page

> syntax:   `error_page` code ... [=[response]] **uri**;

You forgot to specify the `uri` parameter (your `=408` argument has been interpreted as a **uri**).

**upd:**

```
location / {
    error_page 502 504 =408 @empty;
}

location @empty {
    return 200 '';
}
```

Comment: Strange that Nginx accepts to parse the configuration without the uri part. Anyway, I don't have any page to redirect to, I just want to remap an error code, so I guess error_page is not the right way?

Comment: Nginx cannot know is `=408` an URI or not since the code parameter is optional. You must specify a page with error, even if the page will be empty. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Getting inspiration from [Is it possible to change the HTTP status code returned when proxy_pass gateway is down in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237761/), this set of directives appears to work:

```
location = / {
  return 200;
}

location ~ ^[a-z/0-9@A-Z]*$ {
  error_page              502 504 =408 /;

  (proxy configuration goes here)
}
```

Other values for uri did not however.