# no response from nginx server when file exceeds 'client_max_body_size'

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx

On the nginx server the client_max_body_size is set to 10M.

When trying to upload a file larger than 10mb (through AJAX), the request (obviously) fails, but with an empty response. According to [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) this is a known issue with browsers.

I need a concrete way to ascertain that the reason the request failed was because the file was too large. If I were to get the 413 error that would be good enough, but I receive an empty response.

I can not rely solely on client side validation when sending the file.

How can I check that the reason the file upload failed is because it exceeds the client_max_body_size?

Comment: Try changing the error code then. See if something like below helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237761/is-it-possible-to-change-the-http-status-code-returned-when-proxy-pass-gateway-i

Comment: @TarunLalwani that didn't seem to work for me

Comment: Can you post the config you tried?

Comment: server {
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    error_page 413 =403 /error.html;
  }

Comment: sorry linebreaks get edited out

Comment: Hi @joshuamiller did you ever manage to solve this issue? When I upload a file great than the `client_max_body_size` setting, I get an empty error response in Chrome.

Comment: Afraid i dont remember now