# Spring Boot Actuator - shutdown

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using the `actuator/shutdown` endpoint to make graceful shutdown of application. But what I need is to get the *404 Http response* from application when it is in shutdown mode. Is it possible to make such a thing using the actuator?

Comment: Can you describe more detail about your need? I don't understand your need.

Comment: If your application isn't running, what would receive the request and return a 404? Google "application gateway" or "reverse proxy".

Comment: If the application is shutdown it can't possibly provide you a response that you desire. You can front your application with some reverse proxy or other method and provide custom handling. Spring/actuator isn't responsible for what is returned to client once it has shutdown

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Spring Boot 2.3 there is a property [graceful shutdown](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-web-server-shutdown).

```
server.shutdown=graceful
```

It will ensure a 503 (service unavailable) response is returned when shutting down. This seems more appropriate I guess than 404. However, with a reverse proxy such as `nginx` you will be able to [change the status code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088151/480467).